# Apps using location: maps, but maps isn't running

Tags: geolocation, maps

Every few minutes, I can see the following information in the menu bar

[image]

However Maps isn't running and I've never used it recently.

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Can you try to turn off Significant Location? From Apple support : “On Mac, you can turn off Significant Locations by going to System Preferences > Privacy > Location Services, clicking the lock and entering your password, clicking Details next to System Services, then deselecting Significant Locations.”